# Why when i try to start program it doesnt check venv's libs instead of local lib

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, virtualenv

Hi everyone i have an project and i created a venv with

`python -m virtualenv venv`
then i installed requirements for example selenium, pyqt5 etc..
when i want to start my project on powershell i face with this error (venv is activated)

````
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.```

when i try to run with command prompt i also encounter with this error

```from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'```

When i check pip list i can see that all dependencies installed and exist. Why when i try to start program it doesnt check venv's libs instead of local lib. can someone help me. Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: You are skipping the step of activating your virtual environment. https://ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/python-virtual-environment. Refer to this for help.

Comment: I mentioned it above. I encounter these problems when venv is active.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "start my project on powershell"? What happens if you start your program within the active venv with python?

Comment: i mean run the program ex: py main.py

Comment: @kametguler could be a bug of `py.exe` (there has been some regressions with a similar problem in the past). Try to use the actual `python.exe` command

Comment: @musicamante unfortunately still same problem

Comment: Then you probably did something wrong. Please [edit] your post and provide the full procedure you're using.